# Customizing a webpage's css in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, web, customization

I want to customize a site's css and save for Mozilla to load. so that when Mozilla loads an html from that url, it uses my css files instead of the foreign ones.
I dont know how to get Mozilla to do this, when I make a new request to the url, the site's css is loaded instead of mine.
How do I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way for most of us would be using the Mozilla Firefox addon called [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/). It lets you write, save and use own stylesheets for a particular page or domain,  overriding (if necessary) parts of authors own rule(s).

Under the hood it's not much more than built-in Firefox facilities though - you have the `userContent.css` file which, using CSS' own supported `@document` syntax and `!important` after a rule, accomplishes exactly what you're after.

This is all at the heart of CSS actually. It is more or less designed to allow users to override authors stylesheets, and Firefox makes it somewhat easy to do that.

You can obtain a much more extensive explanation [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/userstylesheets/a/aa010906.htm).

Answer (score 1):

For that

You can scan user Agent and find out which browser, its version. Including the OS for OS specific styles
You can use various CSS Hacks for specific browser
Or Scripts or Plugins to indentify the browser and apply various classes to the elements

### Using jQuery

What you're after is known as browser detection:

```
if ($.browser.mozilla) { ...
```

However, browser sniffing is discouraged, as its easy to spoof the user agent, i.e. pretend to be another browser!

You'd best use feature detection, either in your own way, or through the jQuery.support interface: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Here's an article on extending it for your own use: http://www.waytoocrowded.com/2009/03/14/jquery-supportminheight/

### Using PHP

See

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php
http://techpatterns.com/downloads/php-browser-detection-basic.php
http://techpatterns.com/downloads/php_browser_detection.php (contains JS also)
```

Then then create the dynamic CSS file as per the detected browser
Here is a CSS Hacks list

### Selector Hacks

```
/* IE6 and below */
* html #uno  { color: red }

/* IE7 */
*:first-child+html #dos { color: red } 

/* IE7, FF, Saf, Opera  */
html>body #tres { color: red }

/* IE8, FF, Saf, Opera (Everything but IE 6,7) */
html>/**/body #cuatro { color: red }

/* Opera 9.27 and below, safari 2 */
html:first-child #cinco { color: red }

/* Safari 2-3 */
html[xmlns*=""] body:last-child #seis { color: red }

/* safari 3+, chrome 1+, opera9+, ff 3.5+ */
body:nth-of-type(1) #siete { color: red }

/* safari 3+, chrome 1+, opera9+, ff 3.5+ */
body:first-of-type #ocho {  color: red }

/* saf3+, chrome1+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
 #diez  { color: red  }
}

/* iPhone / mobile webkit */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 #veintiseis { color: red  }
}


/* Safari 2 - 3.1 */
html[xmlns*=""]:root #trece  { color: red  }

/* Safari 2 - 3.1, Opera 9.25 */
*|html[xmlns*=""] #catorce { color: red  }

/* Everything but IE6-8 */
:root *> #quince { color: red  }

/* IE7 */
*+html #dieciocho {  color: red }

/* Firefox only. 1+ */
#veinticuatro,  x:-moz-any-link  { color: red }

/* Firefox 3.0+ */
#veinticinco,  x:-moz-any-link, x:default  { color: red  }



/***** Attribute Hacks ******/

/* IE6 */
#once { _color: blue }

/* IE6, IE7 */
#doce { *color: blue; /* or #color: blue */ }

/* Everything but IE6 */
#diecisiete { color/**/: blue }

/* IE6, IE7, IE8 */
#diecinueve { color: blue\9; }

/* IE7, IE8 */
#veinte { color/*\**/: blue\9; }

/* IE6, IE7 -- acts as an !important */
#veintesiete { color: blue !ie; } /* string after ! can be anything */
```

Source: http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

### If you want to use Plugin then here is one

http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the greasemonkey plugin: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/